# White around Python Button

Tags: python, button, background, tkinter

I am using python and adding Button widgets, even though I set the background to grey, there is still a white border around the button. What is the issue?

```
    self.quitButton = Button(parent, text='Quit', command=exit, bg="grey")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, buttons have a border by default. You should be able to get rid of it by specifying `bd=0` as one of the parameters when you create the button.

Comment: Of course, if yoy remove the border you end up with a flat button (except on OSX). Buttons also have a `highlightthickness` attribute which specifies a border for adding highlighting when the widget has focus. When the widget does not have focus, this area will show up as white (or whatever `highlightcolor` is set to).

Comment: @Fred & Bryan, unfortunately none of these solved the issue. The weird part is that menuButton does not have the white...